# Returning string to an ajax call in grails

Tags: ajax, grails, gsp

I have a function sampleFunction() in my Groovy Controller class which I access using an Ajax call in my gsp as

```
var result = ${remoteFunction(controller: 'mycontroller', action: 'sampleFunction',
                                  update: 'none',
                                   params:'\'id=\'+id+\'&content=\'+content+\'&modSubj=\'+modSubj')}
```

How do I return a string from sampleFunction() so that the variable result has the returned value. Please help.

Answer (score 5):

A Grails Controller action can call `render` directly to return some text in the response instead of using a GSP.

```
def sampleFunction() {
    render 'somestring'
}
```

Comment: when i do this will i be able to get the string in my javascript?